# Set a left padding of a class tapping a button from another class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I tried using global variables to reach this:
mainly I have a web app with a sidebar that appear and disappear pressing a button.
I'm trying to use the global variable globals.sidebarWidth. Than the main layout left padding should be the globals.sidebarWidth , that take the value when I press a sidebar button that make the sidebar disappear
This is how it works:

```
import 'globals.dart' as globals;

.... 

 body: Stack(
                    children: [
                      //    if ((screenSize.width > 800) /*&& (menuVisibility)*/)
    
                      Container(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: screenSize.height,
                          width: screenSize.width,
                          child: Image.asset('sfondo-home1.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        ),
                      ),
                      if (screenSize.width > 800) SideBar(),
    
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 50, left: globals.sidebarWidth.toDouble()),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 100,
                          child: Navigator(
                            key: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
                            onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
                            initialRoute: HomeRoute,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Then I want that if I press the arrow button in my SideBar class, all the content float to left "following" the sidebar that is retiring to left and the left padding of my page.

This is from my SideBar class:

```
 Padding(
    padding: menuVisib
        ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 180, top: 400)
        : EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 400),
    child: Container(
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (menuVisib) {
                setState(() {
                  globals.sidebarWidth = 0;
                  menuVisib = false;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  menuVisib = true;
                  globals.sidebarWidth = 200;
                });
                setState(() {});
              }
            },
            child:
                Icon(menuVisib ? Icons.arrow_back : Icons.arrow_forward)),
      ),
    ),
```

But it doesn't work. How should I do? Hope I explained well.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try `AnimatedPositioned`

Comment: No, but the problem is the same. How I set his parameters from another class?